# On Scroll - Add Class - For every element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to the body of my page whenever an element called .swapbg-dark comes into the viewport.

Here is my current code. I have managed to make it work for one of the elements, but when it scrolls past the second it does not retrigger and then removes the class.

JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4xpwaq2g/

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
      var elementTop = $(this).offset().top + 300;
      var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

      var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

      return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };

    $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
      $('.swapbg-dark').each(function() {
        if ($('.swapbg-dark').isInViewport()) {
          $('body').addClass('dark-theme');
        } else {
          $('body').removeClass('dark-theme');
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is for you :

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  var found = false;
  $('.swapbg-dark').each(function() {
    found = found || $(this).isInViewport();
  });
  if (found) {
    $('body').addClass('dark-theme');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('dark-theme');
  }
});
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use `.filter` instead of `.each` and an external variable?

Answer (score 0):

As say @SpoonMeiser , you can do this too :

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  var found = $('.swapbg-dark').filter(function() {
      return $(this).isInViewport();
    }).length !== 0;
  if (found) {
    $('body').addClass('dark-theme');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('dark-theme');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can even remove the *found* variable.